# How to color my data points in PCA plot from tfidfvectorizer matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca, tfidfvectorizer

I'm working on a data-set that I've generated through web-crawling, I have two columns first one is the processed text and the second is the categories. And I wanted to visualize how my data points would look like in a 3D space with PCA.

therefor, I applied a tfidfvectorizer through a subset of my intial data-frame and only took three categories, the matrix was so huge so I reduced the features to 75000 and now I'm trying to visualize my data points with PCA. I already tried doing so with the 20news_group data and it worked wery well. Here is what I tried with my code as far :

```py
d = df.loc[df['Id'].isin(['37','49','23'])] #selecting the categories I wanted

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(d.content, d.Id, test_size = 0.3)
pipe = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range = (1, 2), 
        stop_words = "english", 
        sublinear_tf = True, 
        max_features= 75000))])

X = pipe.fit_transform(X_train)
data = pd.DataFrame(X.todense())
pca = PCA(n_components = 3).fit(data)
data2D = pca.transform(data)


from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
colormap = np.array(['C0', 'C5', 'C8',])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], data2D[:,2], c= colormap[np.array(Y_train)])
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
plt.show()
```

So the expected result should've been all my data points projected in the 3D space generated by PCA axes,  yet I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "***********/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>     File "", line 3, in 
>       ax.scatter(data2D[:,0], data2D[:,1], data2D[:,2], c= colormap[np.array(Y_train)])
>   IndexError: index 37 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3

When I take off the "c" argument it works well but there's no coloring to my data points and I get the following warning :

> UserWarning: This figure includes Axes that are not compatible with tight_layout, so results might be incorrect.
>     warnings.warn("This figure includes Axes that are not compatible "

I thought it was the max_features who did the problem so I did the same with 20news_group data and it worked well too.

Thanks for your Help !